# Adding data to a gridview in c# from multiple forms

Tags: c#, datagridview, project, multiple-forms

How would I go about inserting the text that I have entered in to the textbox in NewActivity into the first column in the datagridview on form1?

Here is the coding I have thus far.

Form1

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.IsMdiContainer = true;
        }

        private void viewToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void newActivityToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NewActivity NewAc = new NewActivity();
            NewAc.MdiParent = this;
            NewAc.Show();
        }

        private void deleteActivityToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

NewActivity

```
 public partial class NewActivity : Form
    {
        public string activityName;

        public NewActivity()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            activityName = "";
            this.Close(); 
        }

        private void btnAddActivity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            activityName = txtActivityName.Text;            
            this.Close();           
        }             
    }
}
```

Comment: your datagrid view is binded to what?

Comment: Need to get the text from the txtActivityName into the first part column of the gridview so it is not bound to a databast or any thing.

Comment: i meant that what is datasource of dataGridView?

Comment: Uhmm, the data source would be txtActivityName(textbox) in the NewActivity form. the text from that text box must go in to the first column of the datagrid view on the Form1

Comment: so basically you are trying to bind data from a textbox to the datagrid..?

Comment: Jip thats it, is it even possible ?

Comment: yes it's possible I will post an example please let me know if this is what you are looking for or not..

Comment: But it has to be data from the text box from one form inserted into another form i.e form NewActivity(form) to Form1(form)

Comment: you should still be able to pass that information from one from to another form and the receiving form you would change the row.CreateCells() method passing variables to that form..same example should work..

Comment: what form is the DataGrid on.. are the textbox and datagrid on the same form..? if not you can also pass the selected information in the portion of code where you create the MDI form.. does this make sense..?

Comment: The DataGrid is in the Form1.cs as is the this.IsMdiContainer and the textbox in the NewActivity.cs, Uhmm makes kind of sense but not total clear on what i should pass in to the part to get the.... Uhmm lol no i dont grasp it sorry

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to bind data from a textbox control to a DataGrid

```
// create new row
DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();

// create cells
row.CreateCells(this.dataGridView1, textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text);

// add to data grid view
this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
```

---------------Below is how you would use it in your case--------------------

```
private void btnAddActivity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   activityName = txtActivityName.Text;    
   int index = dgvActivityList .Rows.Add();
   DataGridViewRow row = dgvActivityList .Rows[index];
   row.Cells[0].Value = activityName;      
   this.Close();           
}
```

Comment: I don't know why but where you say yourDataGridView i know i should put in my gridview's name but it does not appear in the intelisens, it is in 2 different forms that is the text box and the grid view, that is what i cant figure out. Error i get is the name 'mydataGridview' does not exist in the current context ? If they are in the same form i can do it but not if they are in different forms

Comment: what is the name of your DataGrid control on your form..?

Comment: if it's in a different form you need to pass a reference and you have to change the code to fit your names / control names .. don't copy and paste word for word if the names of my example don't match the control names of your controls. I edited my example to match your names so you should be able to be good on that part at least..

Comment: you access properties of the controls by creating and Instance of that particular object.. for example if at design time your control name for a TextBox control is named txtMyTextBox you can't access it from the other form but you can pass that control by ref to another form and or it's constructor.. does this make sense..? Overloaded Constructors

Comment: Will play around with it and see what i can come up with thanx for help

Answer (score 0):

you can insert it in your event click

```
private void btnAddActivity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        activityName = txtActivityName.Text;    
        int index = yourDataGridView.Rows.Add();
       DataGridViewRow row = yourDataGridView.Rows[index];
       row.Cells[0].Value =   activityName ;      
        this.Close();           
    }
```